I want to automaticaly add "+966" to the phone numbers I get in the Google sheet from a Google form response
I have a google form to get phone numbers. I know how to use response validation using regular expressions.
But my question is how to add "+966" to the phone numbers I receive in google form response sheet?

For example in the Google form the input is:

0501234567

I want in the google sheet to be "+966501234567". So it should remove the first value (which is "0") and add the "+966" to it.
I tried using formulas to the column, but each time I get response from Google form it doesn't take effect.

Please show in your question what you tried and what it did or didn't do.

="+966"&VALUE(A1)

@brc-dd
it worked on the existing responses. but when we get a new response the entire row formate is overwritten and it gives blank

Add another sheet on the same spreadsheet and add the formula there. Make that formula reference the sheet that contains the form responses. Simple.

@LeeTaylor, Still the issue is that when a new reponse is made in the google from and its data overwrites all the formula in that cell.
When i created another sheet in the same response sheet used the formula "="+966"&VALUE('Form responses 1'!B:B)" i get thei error - "VALUE parameter 'Number (+9665XXXXXXXX)' cannot be parsed to number."

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zy-Wc6S0ENox9xQALLxml_cS4t9jbAUnUErP_fAsz8o/edit?usp=sharing
This is the link

See my edits on the spreadsheet

Within your shared sheet of Form Responses Column_B seems to accommodate two different styles +966500894188 and 0512345679.  Is that how its going to be in reality as well?!

The sheet i shared is a sample file. In realty the customer will enter the number "0512345678" and this number saved in response sheet in same format. But we need the data in this format +966512345678. So we have to remove the first digit which "0" and add +966 to it.

Formula added to Cell_C1. test it out via your google form

@rockinfreakshow Great!! It worked. Is it possible to copy the formula save it in another sheet ?

Sure... yes you can


Here's one approach you may test out:
=vstack("Formula_",
map(indirect("B2:B"),lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,concat("+966",regexreplace(Σ&"","^0",))))))


